# How to renew Letsencrypt cert using docker

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

The first step in requesting a certificate were super easy:

```
$> sudo docker run -v ./data/certbot:/etc/letsencrypt -it certbot/certbot certonly --preferred-challenges dns --manual
```

When I run this command, it asks for my email address and the domain I want the certificate for and I need to add a DNS record for verification.

Next, I tried to renew the certificate, preferably in a cronjob. I tried:

```
$> sudo docker run -v ./data/certbot:/etc/letsencrypt -it certbot/certbot certonly --preferred-challenges dns --force-renewal
```

But then it asks a question about `.well-known/acme-challenge` but I would like the DNS record of course.

Can someone point me in the direction how I can do this?